# jquery cycle2 reverse flip not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am unable to make work the "reverse" functionality of cycle2 "Flip" transition ?

I have attached the test Html file in [Link to file](http://1drv.ms/N5GXlR). I added the data-cycle-reverse=true to the slideshow div and still it does not work. Can some one help me out ?

Comment: I am unable to make work the "reverse" functionality of cycle2 "Flip" transition ? What do you mean by reverse functionality ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Champ. The default behavior of flipHorz is to flip images from right to left. But I wanted to flip in the opposite direction. Which is left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-cycle-reverse=true` only applies to the order that the slides are displayed, not the animation.

In order to make the Flip transition the opposite direction, you will have to edit the jquery.cycle2.flip.js
You should just have to inverse all of the `90`s in the code.

**Change this (line 50):**

```
        // css before transition start
        rotateFn.call(next, -90);
        next.css({
            'display': 'block',
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'background-position': '-90px',
            'opacity': 1
        });

        curr.css('background-position', '0px');

        curr.animate({ backgroundPosition: 90 }, {
```

**To This:**

```
        // css before transition start
        rotateFn.call(next, 90);
        next.css({
            'display': 'block',
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'background-position': '90px',
            'opacity': 1
        });

        curr.css('background-position', '0px');

        curr.animate({ backgroundPosition: -90 }, {
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bryan. You are correct I did the change and it works  perfectly.